# Do I need a delauny triangulation to find the minimum spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree, delaunay

I understand that the MST is a subset of the delauny triangulation but how can it help to find a minimum spanning tree? What is the meaning when I use an edge of a delauny triangulation for the MST? How is this different from not triangulate a set of points before finding a MST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the standard mst algorithms operate on an graph. if you start with a set of vertices without any other information but the pairwise (abstract) distances between the vertices, your standard approach would require you to run a mst algorithm on the complete graph with `O(n^2)` edges. as the complexity of the standard mst algorithms depend on the number of edges (eg. `O(e log e)` for Kruskal), it would be more efficient if you could curtail the number of edges in the graph to start with - which applies to the delaunay triangulation regarded as a graph since it sports `O(n)` edges (i will not discuss that there is a mst of the original point set being a subset of the delaunay graph, as you acknowledge that).

your original point set might be subject to other constraints that either prevent a delaunay triangulation (eg. collinear points) or allow for a even sparser graph to start with ( eg. a convex hull with a minimum diameter less than the minimum distance between two points in your point set ).

regards, carsten

Comment: Thanks. Is there a rare case when the delauny triangulation adds more edge or doesn't have a solution? Is solution means it reduces the edges?

Comment: collinear points (all points on a single line) are the only border case when there is no solution. however, the mst for this case is trivial. if you have a DT to start with, you will provably always end up with a mst by deleting certain edges.

Comment: Do you have an example of a DT from a TSP graph? Would that help to find a heuristic for a TSP?